# setInterval to incrementally increase/decrease image width

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to write a bit of Javascript that will take an image (at the moment, its just a test image of 500x400 saying "This is a test") and reduce the width every time interval, giving the impression that its a rotating sign; then, when the width reaches zero, the width increases again, making it look like its opening up again.

I've written some untidy code that will need prettying up; at the moment I am just trying to get something to work, but I'm having difficulty it to work can anyone help?

```
<html>
<body>

<center>
<img src="sign.jpg" id="sign" width="500">
</center>

<script>
var decreasing=true;
var currentWidth=500;
var deltaWidth=5;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeWidth() }, 500);

function changeWidth() 
{

if( decreasing == true )
{
currentWidth=-deltaWidth;
document.getElementById("sign").width = currentWidth;

if( currentWidth<=0)
{
    decreasing = false;
}
}
else
{
currentWidth=+deltaWidth;
document.getElementById("sign").width = currentWidth;

if( currentWidth>=500)
{
    decreasing = true;
}
}


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you expecting this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/j0m50uop/1/ ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas I dont think you understood the question

Answer (score 1):

You've got your operators the wrong way around. `=-` and `=+` should be `-=` and `+=`.

```
function changeWidth() 
{

    if( decreasing == true )
    {
        currentWidth -= deltaWidth;

        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that I can see with your code.

1. Your assignment operators are the wrong way round. To increment a value you would use code in the form `i = i + 1`, which i shortened to `i += 1`.
2. Unless you set the height, the browser may want to proportionally resize the `height` when you change the `width` of an image.

The code below works:

```js
var decreasing=true;
var currentWidth=500;
var deltaWidth=5;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeWidth() }, 100);

function changeWidth() 
{

    document.getElementById("sign").height = 400;
    if( decreasing == true )
    {
        currentWidth-=deltaWidth;
        document.getElementById("sign").width = currentWidth;
        if( currentWidth<=0)
        {
            decreasing = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentWidth+=deltaWidth;
        document.getElementById("sign").width = currentWidth;

        if( currentWidth>=500)
        {
            decreasing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="sign" src="http://placehold.it/500x400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your operators are the wrong way. Change `=-` to `-=` and `=+` to `+=`. Also, consider setting a height on the image and speeding up the interval. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da9wd4j4/) to a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change attribute with the setAttribute-Function. And you can do something like this with CSS3 Animate.

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
document.getElementById("sign").style.width = currentWidth + "px"
```

And then use proper css so the image is adjusted like adding

```
max-width: 100%
```

to the image element.

Answer (score -1):

It's not =- but -=. Same story for +=.

```
currentWidth-=deltaWidth;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnbrad32/